# Как вывести меню WP, чтобы ссылка на текущую страницу становилась текстом?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести меню WP, чтобы ссылка на текущую страницу становилась текстом? Возможно, как-то это можно прописать в Walker'e? Заказчик просит так сделать для SEO, я понятия не имею, как это реализовать.

Comment: Заказчик дятел, конечно. Считать себя или своего сеошника умнее команды, создающей WordPress - это признак недалёкости. Однако, раз приходится с такими работать - покажите свой код вывода меню.

Comment: Я даже не представляю как это "ссылка в меню - текстом".. **Убрать** ссылку под пунктом текущей страницы - это другое дело. Хотя и полная ересь от недалёких сеошнегов.